# Limiting the firebase equalTo query with the optional key parameter

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, angularfire2

I have a feeling I may have the understanding of this feature wrong coming from the SQL background. The documentation is sparse and I haven't been able to find a good example or an explanation.
I am looking for a clarification to the following from https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md:

> 1 The Firebase SDK supports an optional key parameter for startAt,
>   endAt, and equalTo when ordering by child, value, or priority. You can
>   specify the key parameter using an object literal that contains the
>   value and the key. For example: startAt: { value: 'some-value', key:
>   'some-key' }.

I want to limit my ordered-by-timestamp-value query (orderByChild) using this optional key parameter to restrict the results only to those were a child key has a specified value.

```
this.angularFireDatabase.list('/items', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'uploadedOn_',
    equalTo: { key: 'user_uid', value: 'fSXX9twkttYqoS67mcRUmPawIep1' }
  }
});

// JSON 
{
  "items" : {
    "-KijNTXRKV5rjXEA7NdO" : {
      "uploadedOn_" : -1493296081615,
      "user_uid" : "fSXX9twkttYqoS67mcRUmPawIep1"
    },
    "-KijNoB4MivU4Ts6XgUV" : {
      "uploadedOn_" : -1493296169733,
      "user_uid" : "fSXX9twkttYqoS67mcRUmPawIep1"
    },
    "-KijbTMBydwQexbbErlk" : {
      "uploadedOn_" : -1493300012491,
      "user_uid" : "EAsIjLDFPRZDTq97qGQQyS7sBul1"
    }
  }
}
```

Perhaps, I'm trying to mimic the where SQL clause when instead I should be structuring my data differently.
It seems that this optional `key` parameter can only be the item's own key.
In my example it's the regular auto-generated Firebase push key (e.g. `"-KijNTXRKV5rjXEA7NdO"`).
But in this case I'm confused as to what the use case would be to use `equalTo` together with `orderByChild` if the result will always be a single item you could get to by NOT using the optional `key` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `ref.orderBy("prop").equalTo("value", "key")` it'll give the same results as `ref.child("key")`. The second parameter for `equalTo()` is essentially useless (unlike for `startAt()` and `endAt()`, where it can be used to slice a range.

Also see:

- [Firebase Query order by and start at name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376331/firebase-query-order-by-and-start-at-name/43376894#43376894)
- [How to paging query from Firebase using Android FirebaseUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278544/how-to-paging-query-from-firebase-using-android-firebaseui/41285470#41285470)